# Amount of pixel eroded

Tags: image-processing, morphological-operations, morphology

Is there a definite relation between the kernel size and shape of a morphology change and the amount of pixels added or removed?

I have a case where I have a segmented image, and I need to remove x number of pixels all around the boundary of specific segmentations. I have therefore thought that a circular kernel with radius of x should be used. Then would one iteration of eroding remove x pixels, i.e., can I assume that the radius will correspond to the amount of pixels removed all around the segmentation?

Comment: The question seems incomplete (?), but so far the answer is "Yes".

Comment: @A_A sorry - yes, it is added now. It is basically to ensure my understanding that I can know how many pixels I erode a given segmentation with, using a kernel with a radius of x pixels